# Interpretation of Autocorrelation plot

Tags: python, time-series

I am trying to understand better how to read the autocorrelation plot here for a timeseries data.

I ran the following code and got the output as a chart show below.

```
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
autocorrelation_plot(df("y"))
```

Here y is the dependent variable

[image: Autocorrelation plot]

Should I derive the following conclusions

- There are no significant autocorrelations.
- The data is random.
- Most of the correlations (except for 2 lags) fall within 95% confidence limits
- This timeseries is not worth forecasting

Please help me if my understanding is right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your points:

- **There are no significant autocorrelations**

  The correlation is low (~0.25), but there are significant autocorrelations.
- **The data is random & most of the correlations (except for 2 lags) fall within 95% confidence limits**

  The confidence intervals are used to show which autocorrelations are significant. As you rightly observed, a couple peaks jump out of this region and this tells us that these few correlations are statistically significant, the rest is random. [This post may be helpful here](https://otexts.com/fpp2/wn.html#wn).
- **This timeseries is not worth forecasting**

  As per the previous point, there are a couple of statistically significant weak correlations in this dataset. But they are not strong, so a periodicity based forecasting model probably wouldn't be very accurate.

Comment: Thank you. This helped !